# Can I use public key to generate private key?

Tags: openssl, private-key, public-key

I am using OpenSSL to generate private key.
Currently, I have public key on hand, can I generate private key according the public key by using OpenSSL.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, you can‘t. Otherwise everyone could create private keys for every public key, which would result in a non-sense for using SSL keys because the security aspect were lost.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 3):

No, and with good reason.

If you could do this a private key would no longer be private because everybody would be able to generate it based on a public key and everybody would be able to sign any document with the generated private key, pretending to be the issuer of the public key.